# is there a way to prevent Pivot table from resetting cumulative value each year? the cumulative value is derived from count of dates in raw data

Tags: excel, database, pivot-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYZb9.png)

The pivot chart display the cumulative value (Green line) however i would need it on a per year basis
when i do it split by year i get this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSIN.png)

my red line is my baseline and the green lines is my count of dates which is cumulative however as shown on the second screenshot it it dips when it goes into the second year.

Tried checking formulas and lookign at using power pivot but cant seem to get it right